# Windows 10 - Ask for a password when the display is off

Tags: windows-10, sleep, lock

I want the computer to require to enter a password after, say, 5 minutes but I don't want to put it to sleep. I was able to do it in Windows 7 but I couldn't figure out in Windows 10. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "Change Screen Saver" to open the Screen Saver Settings.  From there, you can select any screensaver (or "Blank"), and check the box that says "On resume, display logon screen".

Comment: This timeout ends up being different from the display off timeout. For example on a laptop I can have 2 different display off timeouts. But this screen saver lock screen timeout only has 1 setting. Is there really no way to set lock screen display to trigger on display off and not depend on screen saver timeout?

Comment: For reference see: https://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/11685-password-protection-wakeup-enable-disable-windows-8-a.html It was available in Windows 8.